# Python Regex for java method signature with preceding comments and without class attributes declaration

Tags: java, python, regex, method-signature

I am trying to do a regular expression in python that matches every method signature in a java file with the preceding comments (if comments exist). But at the same time, I dont want it to match class attribute declaration.
my code is:

```
st:'''
/**
 class attribute comments
 */
private Type class_attribute1;

private Type class_attribute2;

/**
 * method1 comments.
 */
public Returnvalue method1(arguments OR no arguments) {
    method1 body
}

private Returnvalue method2(arguments OR no arguments) {
           method2 body
}'''

   import re

   print re.findall(r"([/][*].*?[*][/].*?(public|private|protected).*?{|\s(public|private|protected).*?{)", st, re.DOTALL)
```

but it also print the class attribute comments and declaration!

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

1) Your regex `(public|private|protected).*` is too broad - it can't distinguish between class attributes (which end in *;* and cannot contain *[(){}]*) and method prototypes (which must contain parentheses *(..)* and then a body *{...}* and cannot end in *;* )
So just write a better regex.

2) Also, your regex will need [capture groups](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax). Then don't use `re.findall`, use a match object and [only extract the group you want, i.e. the actual declaration](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#match-objects)